# How to create a drop down menu with anchors?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create one drop down menu with anchors. The drop down menu and anchors are on the same HTML page.

I’m beginner concerning Javascript I tried this code but I don’t find how execute the click.

Thank you for your help.

```js
function selection () {
  var choicemenu = document.getElementById('choicemenu');
  choicemenu.addEventListner('click',selection);
  choicemenu.onclick = ;
}
```

```html
<select id=choicemenu>
  <option selected>Choose</option> 
  <option href="#c1"><a>Category 1</a></option> 
  <option href="#c2"><a>Category 2</a></option>
</select> 

<p>
  <div id="c1">Category 1</div> 
  <div id="c2">Category 2</div> 
</p>
```

Comment: And what are you asking for? What's the problem? Please describe it in details!

Comment: The name of your variable is `choicemenu`, but you're adding the event listener to something called `menuchoix`. 

Also take a look at examples here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp

Comment: Or, rather, on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). @amy8374 Please, don't recommend W3Schools, if possible, because it's a low quality information source...

Comment: @amy8374 : My bad I edited it also.

Comment: More details as asked : When someone clicks on a category in the menu, he must be directly positioned at the chosen category level (lower in the page), but I do not find how to execute the procedure with Javascript.

Comment: I'd also move the `selection` function declaration before it getting used. Open up the dev console, see what type of errors you get.

Comment: @amy8374 : I have edited and i have this message ==> Error: {
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0
}

Comment: What are you trying to do when the option is selected? Are you trying to scroll to the corresponding div anchor?

Comment: @Steve K : yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for this. If I misunderstood I beg your pardon

```js
function selection () {
var choicemenu = document.getElementById("choicemenu");
var option=choicemenu.options[choicemenu.selectedIndex];
//if you want to do something onclick or you can skip the below line
option.onclick=test;
//click the anchor
option.click();
}

function test(){
alert("do what you want to do here");
}
```

```html
<select id=choicemenu onchange="selection()";>

<option selected>Choose</option> 
<option><a href="#c1">Category 1</a></option> 
<option><a href="#c2">Category 2</a></option>

</select> 

<p>
<div id="c1">Category 1</div> 
<div id="c2">Category 2</div> 
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you but i think it's not adapted for me because for my case the anchors are on the same page of the drop down menu.

Comment: change th url as you desire

Comment: Thank you your code (which work for url) is near of my search, I want change "Value" by "Href". Indeed the visitors must stay on the website and be forwarded to an anchor in the same page of the drop down menu.

Comment: you want to scroll to the selected href position?

Comment: Thank you for the code. For resume, if the visitor clicks on <option><a href="#c1">Category 1</a></option> he will be positioned to <div id="c1">Category 1</div>

Answer (score 0):

Idk if your set on using a select for this but you really should be using a dropdown.  Your going to run into issues with the select most notably that the default doesn't have any value to it.  Also I don't believe the href attribute is a valid attribute of an option tag.  You also have a div inside a p tag which is invalid html.  That being said you can achieve this with scrollintoview.  This feature is pretty well supported now.  You can see the support tables here https://caniuse.com/#feat=scrollintoview.  And read on scrollintoview here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView.  If you don't want the smooth scrolling behavior there will be no reason to use javascript at all you can just use the native href anchors and snap to sections that way.  But here is an example with the dropdown:

```js
const scrollTriggers = document.querySelectorAll('#choicemenu a');
scrollTriggers.forEach(scrollTrigger => {
  scrollTrigger.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const hash = this.hash;
    const scrollTarget = document.querySelector(hash);
    scrollTarget.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
  })
})
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-toggle{
  padding:5px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  display:inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
  max-height:100px;
  overflow:auto;
}

.dropdown-content a{
  display:block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

/* heights just for demo purposes */
#c1,#c2,#c3,#c4,#c5,#c6,#c7,#c8 {
  height:500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <span class="dropdown-toggle">Choose One &#9660;</span>
  <div id="choicemenu" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#c1">Category1</a>
    <a href="#c2">Category2</a>
    <a href="#c3">Category3</a>
    <a href="#c4">Category4</a>
    <a href="#c5">Category5</a>
    <a href="#c6">Category6</a>
    <a href="#c7">Category7</a>
    <a href="#c8">Category8</a>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="c1">Category 1</div> 
<div id="c2">Category 2</div>
<div id="c3">Category 3</div> 
<div id="c4">Category 4</div>
<div id="c5">Category 5</div> 
<div id="c6">Category 6</div>
<div id="c7">Category 7</div> 
<div id="c8">Category 8</div>
```

or you can use jquery which would look like the following:

```js
$('#choicemenu a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  const hash = this.hash;
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-toggle{
  padding:5px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  display:inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow:auto;
}

.dropdown-content a{
  display:block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

/* heights just for demo purposes */
#c1,#c2,#c3,#c4,#c5,#c6,#c7,#c8 {
  height:500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <span class="dropdown-toggle">Choose One &#9660;</span>
  <div id="choicemenu" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#c1">Category1</a>
    <a href="#c2">Category2</a>
    <a href="#c3">Category3</a>
    <a href="#c4">Category4</a>
    <a href="#c5">Category5</a>
    <a href="#c6">Category6</a>
    <a href="#c7">Category7</a>
    <a href="#c8">Category8</a>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="c1">Category 1</div> 
<div id="c2">Category 2</div>
<div id="c3">Category 3</div> 
<div id="c4">Category 4</div>
<div id="c5">Category 5</div> 
<div id="c6">Category 6</div>
<div id="c7">Category 7</div> 
<div id="c8">Category 8</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the code! I will follow your advice, I used "Select" because I need a drop-down menu that must contain 83 categories/subcategories. I searched and did many tests, but I can not reproduce the same presentation (with the vertical scrollbar) as the "Select" could have done. Where can I find this informations ?

To test the code I wrote <script> const scrollTriggers ......... ... "smooth"}); })}) </ script>, but I read in the code "Jquery" therefore should I write for example <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2 /jquery.min.js ">?

Thanks again.

Comment: I edited my answer to clean up some code, added an example with jquery and to include a max height for the dropdown menu with a scrollbar.  You can use a max-height and overlow auto in your css for that.  As for jquery the first example I gave you doen't require jquery I have added another example that uses jquery.  If you use the one with jquery you just add the script linking to jquery in the foot section of your page and then the code after you link to jquery in a seperate script tag.  Jquery may be better because it is less buggy and has better browser support.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Hello, Your first code gives me an error message when I click on "run code snippet", but the one with jsquery is perfect. I found that it was a bit abrupt for the user to go directly to the anchor, so I integrated your code to make it more fluid. Everything works perfectly. Thank you and others for taking the time to help me.